# Upgrade from one Jessie to another

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I am loading Jessie using Berryboot and I note it is from September 2015. This is too early as I need the latest version with Node-Red built in and some recent changes.

I see lots of threads about upgrading from Wheezy to Jessie - but what are the series of instructions (as user Pi) for ensuring I move from an older version of Jessie to the latest?

Any takers?

Comment: Joan's answer is correct but just to clarify some semantics: There are not really multiple versions of Jessie; the software is updated constantly (which is why you should consider running those commands on a regular basis, at least weekly).  One might refer to "a more recent version", but there is really only one Jessie, there is just the potential for different *installations* to fall behind one another in terms of updates.  I.e., it would be more correct to say "an install updated to 1-6-16", etc. The SD card images, as you notice, are snapshots from a particular point in time.

Answer (score 5):

I run the following script on an ad hoc basis.  I call it update and it lives in `/usr/local/bin`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH
sudo apt-get -yq update
#
sudo apt-get -yq upgrade
sudo apt-get -yq dist-upgrade
#
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

It updates the repositories indexes (update) and then upgrades (upgrade and dist-upgrade) all the packages.  Finally it gets rid of any newly orphaned packages.

It ensures I'm up to date with the Raspbian and raspberrypi.org repositories.

EDITED TO ADD

`/usr/local/bin` is normally in the program path so the script can be run by simply typing `update`.

However the script must first have been made executable with the command

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/update`

Comment: Understand the commands - thanks.  Just for anyone looking in - when making that file - you need to set execute permissions or you're told it is not found when running sudo update... all of which seems a bit daft when clearly it is found :-)

Comment: Something with the execute permission is not surprisingly flagged as "executable" but that can be a text script as well as a ELF or a.out or all sorts of other binary file.  Without that bit (and the absence of a `noexec` option in the `/etc/fstab` entry for the filesystem where the file resides)  the kernel/shell will ignore it as something it can run - which is a useful safety step if the binary or script is not compatible for THIS OS but is being stored or served to a different platform.  Remember everything in *NIX is a file...

Comment: @PeterScargill added note about executable bit.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

Then, it's best practice to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` after.

---

`apt-get update` refreshes the package index files from sources listed on `/etc/apt/sources.list`

`apt-get upgrade` will fetch new versions of packages that are installed on your system. This command **will fail if there are conflicting packages**, hence the need for `apt-get dist-upgrade`. The versions it will install depend on the index `apt-get update` downloaded, so running `apt-get update` beforehand is important.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` does the same thing as `apt-get upgrade`, but handles changing dependencies. It will attempt to upgrade more important packages at the expense of less important ones. Some packages may be automatically removed.

The `-y` switch tells `apt-get` to answer yes on any questions it might ask.

The `&&` part tells whatever is running the command to execute the second command if the first is successful. So an `apt-get upgrade` won't happen if ever `apt-get update` fails.

[(Source)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8)